# mount printing to terminal when called with subprocess.check_output()

Tags: python, subprocess, mount

According to the [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), ***subprocess.check_output(...)*** should return the output of the process, and raise a *CalledProcessError* exception if the return code is non-zero, with the output in the ***output*** attribute.

This works well if I try something like `subprocess.check_output(["ls"])` where I get the string as a return value. However, when I try

```
subprocess.check_output(shlex.split("mount -t cifs //server/share /local_rep"))
```

it directly prints to terminal *"mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)"* and the ***output*** attribute of the exception raised is empty - ***returncode*** and ***cmd*** are set correctly.

How can I make it so that nothing is output directly to the terminal, and that error messages are stored in ***output***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
subprocess.check_output(args, *, stdin=None, stderr=None, shell=False, universal_newlines=False)
```

'mostly' passes its arguments directly to the Popen constructor:

```
class subprocess.Popen(args, bufsize=0, executable=None, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, preexec_fn=None, close_fds=False, shell=False, cwd=None, env=None, universal_newlines=False, startupinfo=None, creationflags=0),
```

where the default `stdin/stdout/stderr=None` means that "no redirection will occur; the child's file handles will be inherited from the parent." One'd notice that `subprocess.check_output(...)` does not have `stdout` as an argument. That is because `stdout` is used internally - that is where the return value or ***output*** attribute are taken from. However, `stderr=None` is still the default, which means that, in this case, errors are printed directly to the terminal and are not picked up by `check_output()` and returned with the exception.

One possible solution is to pass `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to `subprocess.check_output(...)` so that error messages are sent to `STDOUT`, therefore not printed to terminal, and stored in ***output*** in case of an exception.

Comment: -1 Why did you ask this question and post a self-answer? There is no new information in it, just read the documentation on `stderr` and `stdout`, e.g. in the [check_output](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) section -> **To also capture standard error in the result, use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`**.

Comment: I figured out the answer as  I was writing the question; figured I might as well post it, somebody could find it useful at some point. It's quite an obvious answer, in hindsight, but having missed that line it wasn't clear to me, having also assumed that the default `stdin/stdout/stderr=None` meant that it was handled internally, not left inherited from the parent process.